# How to center a UIButton that is a header to a section in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 5 different sections. For one of those sections I have added a `UIButton` by doing:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section == 5) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];


    [button1 setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    button1.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 96, 44);



    [view addSubview:button1];


    return view;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The problem that I am having is this: Since the Header for a section is by default aligned to the left, button is being aligned to the left, I have looked all around for a solution but can't seem to find one, your help/advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing here gets aligned by itself, really. What you do here is creating a canvas view for your section header, which is correct, and then you position your button with origin of `(8, 8)` which is roughly upper left corner. Just set proper origin coordinates and you'll be set.

You should take a look at CGRect* family of function [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html), to make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

No alignment factors, jusst the point that  `button1.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 96, 44);` sets the frame of your button set it centered to the view then it will show as so